# PHP Composer on AWS beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run a PHP application on AWS Beanstalk. However I have an error when I upload the zipped file containing the dependencies of the project already installed using composer.

Does Beanstlak run composer.json when the application is deployed? does it take into account the already existing vendor folder in the zip ?

This is the error after deploying :

```
PHP Warning: include(Redis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/application/bootstrap.php on line 28. URI is /index.php/transaction/bootPHP Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Redis.php' for inclusion
```

Comment: If it runs composer, anything that already exists in the vendor folder should be overwritten by composer. What error are you getting? Is it while uploading or when you run the application after you've uploaded them?

Comment: yes the error if after uploading, all the deployment goes fine, but when accessing the URL i am getting the error